# Count number of rows from sum

Tags: sql, count, sum, having

I'm trying to count number of rows that are >= 1 OR <= -1 based on sum(rtime-time).

My table

```
aono | aopos | artno | flogr | prgr | rtime | time |    rdate     |
7132 |  10   | 1234  |   20  |  20  |   2   |  1   | 2017-08-24   |
7132 |  10   | 1234  |   30  |  30  | 1,3   |  1   | 2017-08-24   |
7132 |  20   | 5678  |   20  |  29  |   1   |  3   | 2017-08-24   |
7132 |  20   | 5678  |   30  |  31  | 0,4   |  1,5 | 2017-08-24   | 
7132 |  50   |  12   |   10  |  10  | 0,5   |  0,5 | 2017-08-24   |
```

I've made this query.

```
SELECT aono, aopos, artno, flogr, prgr, sum(rtime-time) AS Diff 
FROM dbo.ao
WHERE (rdate Between '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-31') AND (flogr = '20' OR flogr = '30')
GROUP BY aono, aopos, artno, flogr, prgr
HAVING SUM(rtime-time) >= '1' OR SUM(rtime-time) <= '-1'
```

That returns the following result

```
aono | aopos | artno | flogr | prgr | Diff
7132 |  10   | 1234  |   20  |  20  |   1      
7132 |  20   | 5678  |   20  |  29  |  -2   
7132 |  20   | 5678  |   30  |  31  |  -1,1
```

So what i need help with is to create a query that counts the number of rows (Diff) based on the query above. In this example the correct result would be 3.

Thanks in advance

/SisU

Comment: Wrap your current query up in a derived table, and count its rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there just use `COUNT`

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT aono, aopos, artno, flogr, prgr, sum(rtime-time) AS Diff 
    FROM dbo.ao
    WHERE (rdate Between '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-31') AND (flogr = '20' OR flogr = '30')
    GROUP BY aono, aopos, artno, flogr, prgr
    HAVING SUM(rtime-time) >= '1' OR SUM(rtime-time) <= '-1')
) t
```

Comment: That easy huh. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the `COUNT` on your query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT aono, aopos, artno, flogr, prgr, sum(rtime-time) AS Diff 
FROM dbo.ao
WHERE (rdate Between '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-31')
AND (flogr = '20' OR flogr = '30')
GROUP BY aono, aopos, artno, flogr, prgr
HAVING SUM(rtime-time) >= '1' OR SUM(rtime-time) <= '-1')
```